# What can I do if my I2C library of the PIC16F18855 doesnt work?

Tags: c, pic, microchip

I'm trying to write my own I2C library with the PIC16LF18855. Unfortunately without success. My Interrupt-flag (SSP1IF) never occurs. I tried to debugg the whole software and looking at every register. Everything seems to be written correct. But I look in the SSP1STAT register the "S" bit (bit3, Start bit, Indicates that a Start bit has been detected last) never gets set. The Hardware should be correct because if I use the MCC generated library it works. I can't find out what the issue might or could be.

I tried to make a new project with just the I2C stuff in it also without success. Debugged the whole project without success as well.

This is my I2C.c file

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "I2C.h"

uint8_t dummy = 0;

void I2C_Init(void){
    SSP1CLKPPS = 0x13;   //RC3->MSSP1:SCL1;    
    RC3PPS = 0x14;   //RC3->MSSP1:SCL1;    
    RC4PPS = 0x15;   //RC4->MSSP1:SDA1;    
    SSP1DATPPS = 0x14;   //RC4->MSSP1:SDA1;    
    TRISC3 = 0;
    TRISC4 = 0;
    ANSC3 = 0;
    ANSC4 = 0;
    //Mastermode
    //clock = FOSC/4*(SSPxADD+1)
    SSP1STAT = 0x00;
    SSP1CON1 = 0x08;
    SSP1CON2 = 0x00;
    //clock = FOSC/32
    SSP1ADD = 0x1F;

}
void I2C_Open(void){
    //Enable I2C
    SSPEN1 = 1;
}

void I2C_Close(void){
    SSPEN1 = 0;
}

void I2C_Start(void){
    SEN1 = 1;
    while(SEN1);
}

void I2C_Stop(void){ 
    PEN1 = 1;
    while(PEN1);
}

uint8_t I2C_SendADD(uint8_t address, uint8_t RW){
    SSP1BUF = (address << 1) + RW;
    if(WCOL1){
        WCOL1 = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    while(BF1);
    return ACKSTAT1;
}

uint8_t I2C_SendDATA(uint8_t data){
    SSP1BUF = data;
    if(WCOL1){
        WCOL1 = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    return ACKSTAT1;
}

uint8_t I2C_Write(uint8_t adresse, uint8_t RW, uint8_t dataSize, uint8_t *dataArrayPointer){
    I2C_Start();
    //die Adresse wird gesendet
    SSP1BUF = (adresse << 1) + RW;
    if(WCOL1){
        WCOL1 = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    while(BF1);
    for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++){
        SSP1BUF = dataArrayPointer[i];
        if(WCOL1){
            WCOL1 = 0;
            return 1;
        }
        if(i >= dataSize){
            i = 0;
        }
        while(BF1);
        
    }
    I2C_Stop();
    return 0;
}
```

In my main file:

```
while(1){
        I2C_Open();
        I2C_Start();
        debuggVal = I2C_SendADD(0x7C, W);
        debuggVal = I2C_SendDATA(0xAF);
        I2C_Stop();
        I2C_Close();
    }
```

if I would check for "while(!SSP1IF)" in the Start function it should be set but never does get set
If anyone sees something odd please tell me

Comment: At first glance, there is something odd with your main loop.  You basically open and then shutdown your SSP device repeatedly.  Why?  Get the basic functionality running, then test the stop/shutting down functions, which can only be useful for power-saving.  In other words, you should open the device outside the loop, then loop sending data, with an appropriate delay.  Then go on to test more functionnality.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy thank you for your reply. It was just to see if my I2C even sends anything. But now it does work